# If $f:X\to X$ is an epimorphism, which of these statements are true?

Tags: linear-algebra

> $X$ is a linear space, $\dim X = n < \infty$.  $f:X\to X$ is epimorphism. Then:
>   a. $f$ is monomorphism.
>   b. there is exists base such that matrix of $f$ is diagonal.
>   c. there is exists base such that matrix of $f$ is symmetric.

a. is true, because:
Let $A$ be matrix of $f$. Since, $A$ is matrix of change base then this matrix is non-singular, so it is reversible.  Then $Ax=0\Leftrightarrow A^{-1}Ax=A^{-1}0 \Leftrightarrow x = 0$ so  $f$ is monomorphism.

b. No idea,
c. No idea,

What about a. ? Is it correct ? Can you help me with b., c. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (a), your argument isn't really complete; I'd say you haven't fully justified how you know $A$ is a change-of-basis matrix.

But there's actually no need to talk about matrices at all, just use the rank-nullity theorem, the fact that $X$ is finite-dimensional, and the fact that

- $f$ is an epimorphism $\iff$ $\operatorname{im}(f)=X$
- $f$ is a monomorphism $\iff$ $\ker(f)=0$

---

For (b), remember that

- $f$ is diagonalizable $\iff$ $\mathrm{algmult}(\lambda)=\mathrm{geomult}(\lambda)$ for every eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $f$

Take a look at a linear map like $f\left(\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, which (you can check) is indeed an epimorphism.

---

The above map is also a good example to think about for part (c). Can there be a basis $\left\{\bigl\lbrack\begin{smallmatrix}a\\c\end{smallmatrix}\bigr\rbrack ,\bigl\lbrack\begin{smallmatrix}b\\d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr\rbrack\right\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ in which the linear map given above is symmetric? Equivalently, can there be an invertible matrix $\bigl\lbrack\begin{smallmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{smallmatrix}\bigr\rbrack$ (which remember, is equivalent to $ad-bc\neq 0$) such that
$$\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}&=\begin{bmatrix}a & a+b\\ c & c+d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\ c & d\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\\[0.1in]
&=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}a & a+b\\ c & c+d\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\hphantom{-}d & -b\\ -c & \hphantom{-}a\end{bmatrix}\\[0.1in]
&=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}ad-ac-bc & a^2\\ -c^2 & -bc+ac+ad\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}$$
is symmetric?

Comment: When it comes to (b) I don't understand you. How to count eigenvalues for matrix of $f$ ? After all, we don't know this matrix - it depend on base...

Comment: @J.Doe: The eigenvalues of a linear transformation don't change, no matter what basis you choose. Algebraic multiplicity and geometric multiplicity are defined [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors_of_matrices)

Comment: So eigenvalues and eigenvectors of linear transformation are the same for each base (matrix in this base). So, you could choose canonical base.